# match the name with email if they are exact

Tags: r

I have a data frame of large number of name and email and i have to check if name and name email are macthed.but this is not working for me.

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("ccc,bb","tt,dy","anz kpw, p","timm,ral","dj war, amz","lew, wey","sun, mark"),
   email = c("ram.dain@tttt.com",   "dy.tt@aquan@tttt.com", "p.kpw.anz@tttt.com",   "frez.tal@tttt.com",    "amz.djwar@tttt.com",   "wey.lew@tttt.com", "wall.kit@tttt.com"))

df <- df %>%
  separate(name,
           into = c("last_name", "first_name"),
           sep = separator,
           remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(first_name = tolower(first_name),
         last_name = tolower(last_name)) %>%
  mutate(name_email_match = 0L*str_detect(email,
                                          paste0("^", first_name, separator, last_name,
                                                 "@\\w+\\.com$"))) %>%
  select(-c(first_name, last_name))
```

the output should be like

[image]

Comment: just updated again

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% mutate(namematch =  +(!str_detect(email, str_remove_all(str_replace(name, "(.*),\\s*(\\w+)", "\\2.\\1"), "\\s+"))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this should work.  We extract the words from the 'name', 'email' (after removing the suffix starting with `@`), then we loop over each of the `list` elements, collapse the split elements into a single expression with `|`, use that in `str_detect` to check whether those elements are `all` present, negate (`!`) and coerce to integer (`+`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
df %>%
    mutate(name_match = map2_int(str_extract_all(name, "\\w+"), 
      str_extract_all(str_remove(email, "\\@.*"), "\\w+"),
              ~ +(!all(str_detect(.y, str_c(.x, collapse="|"))))))
```

-output

```
#          name                email name_match
#1      ccc,bb    ram.dain@tttt.com          1
#2       tt,dy dy.tt@aquan@tttt.com          0
#3  anz kpw, p   p.kpw.anz@tttt.com          0
#4    timm,ral    frez.tal@tttt.com          1
#5 dj war, amz   amz.djwar@tttt.com          0
#6    lew, wey     wey.lew@tttt.com          0
#7   sun, mark    wall.kit@tttt.com          1
```

Comment: prefect its working , but please explain little about it

Comment: @sanuali0123 thanks, i added some explanation.  Hope it helps